# Select max difference between 2 rows with the same value (Statistics)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with some values inserted on a daily basis, something like this

```
-----------
id | count
-----------
1  | 97
2  | **97**
3  | 59   
4  | 62
5  | 47
6  | 59 
7  | 59 
8  | **97**   
-----------
```

I need to get the max day difference between repeated values, i.e, as you can see the 1st and 2nd value is 97, that is 1 day difference, but the next occurrence of 97 is 6 days later, so I need to get this "Max" difference (6).

same thing for 59, the max day difference is 3 days (3) -- between day 3 and 6.
At this moment I`m using php arrays like this Example:

```
$q = " SELECT id FROM table WHERE VALUE = 97 "; 
// etc ... the array looks like this
$array = {1, 2, 8};
```

then I get the "Max" difference, but I just want to know if there is any way to do this in mysql, thanks

EDIT:

```
//if we list only the column "count":
44  5  *97*  74  5  **97**  7  3  2  31  9  8  4  2  1  **97**  4  7  7  8  *97*
```

step1 : "97" is in 3rd position, then in 6th position (diff = 3) 
step2 : "97" is in 6th position, then in 16th position (diff = 10) 
step3 : "97" is in 16th position, then in 21st position (diff = 5) 
step4 : MAX diff = **10**

**I must complain about this, I posted this question at 08:59 AM, I reloaded the page 1 minute later (At 9:00) and it was already down-voted, there was no time to read and understand the question, this is absurd**

Comment: I must complain about this, I posted this question at 08:59 AM, I reloaded the page 1 minute later (At 9:00) and it was already down-voted, there was no time to read and understand the question, this is absurd

Comment: You were probably down-voted due to a lack of clarity in your post. As @Strawberry asked, is "ID" the same as your "day"?

Comment: Yep, SO is a fickle place.

Comment: @Andrew that means being down-voted?, the questions is clear, "Daily basis" means no mater if is a day or ID, I need to get that difference, also there were 2 answers before that comment, besides Strawberry posted that comment 30 minutes after someone else down-voted my question

Comment: Well, I would have just asked for more info, not down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both work:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/243f2/22

```
select a.blahday ad, max(b.blahday) bd, a.blahday - max(b.blahday) diff from blah a join blah b using (blahcount)
  where blahcount = 97
    and a.blahday > b.blahday
  group by ad
  order by diff desc
  limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/243f2/25

```
select a.blahday ab,
  (select max(blahday) from blah where blahcount = a.blahcount and blahday < a.blahday) bd
  from blah a
where blahcount = 97
order by ab - bd desc
limit 1
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/243f2/22 -- Works perfect, thanks a lot! I prefer thisone because it does not have a nested select

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
(`a`.`max_id` - `b`.`min_id`) as `max_day_diff`, `a`.`count`
from
(select max(id) as `max_id`, `count`
    from `table` group by `count`
) a
inner join
(select min(id) as `min_id`, `count`
 from `table` group by `count`
 ) b
 on `a`.`count` = `b`.`count`
```

This is the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a6a3/10

This will give max_day_diff as 0 for rows with only one count value (like 62, 47 in your case)

Comment: Hey Maximus, I tried this but this returs the difference between the first and last occurrence, not the max difference between values (i.e 1 2 1 3 5 7 5 7 8 2 2 1 0 0 9 7 8 1 -- as you can see the 1 is first and last, but the max difference is between position 3 and 12, that would be a difference of 9 )

Comment: Can you update your question with the output that you are looking for ?

Comment: The update made it a bit more confusing than before. I am not sure what you are looking for here. If what you are looking for works using PHP and you are getting the desired output then I would highly recommend that you use PHP in place of MySQL. In order for this thing to work using MySQL only, you might need to make changes to your database structure and I am not sure how feasible would that be for you.

Comment: I edited the question again, but you might be right, this is a php job

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you're looking for.

[SQLFiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/243f2/7)

That's a pretty funky table you've got there, btw.

Comment: thanks Andrew, but same problem, this gets the difference between the fist and the last occurrence

Comment: So you want to look at each gap, and then find the max of those gaps?  I don't think you can do that kind of row by row processing in pure SQL.